# How can NonNull be made thread safe in Rust?

Tags: windows, rust, thread-safety

I cannot send non null type between threads in rust. I need to call a method on a NonNull pointer for the Windows rust API.

I have tried `Arc<Mutex<NonNull>>` and `Arc<Mutex<RefCell<Box<NonNull>>>` but cannot find a way to get send and sync for NonNull.

I would like the thread to halt and await the mutex, so calling a method or even mutating the NonNull type shouldnt be a threading problem but even with runtime borrow checking I get the error: 'NonNull<c_void> cannot be sent between threads safely'
and then a list of:

> required because of the requirements on the impl of 'Send'

..etc.

I am about to try passing in the method as dyn but this should be possible right?

Comment: If you know the pointer is safe to send, you can inform the compiler of that: `struct MyNonNull(NonNull); unsafe impl Send for MyNonNull {}`

Comment: Is there any way to have the thread halt on locking NonNull instead? Even if it isnt safe to send it should be able to be passed between threads with proper locks and halts?

Comment: You can implement `Sync` the same way, but I'm really not sure what you mean by "have the thread halt". You don't need locking to access the pointer, you need it to access what's behind the pointer, and you certainly can (and should) use a mutex for that.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html
"raw pointers are, strictly speaking, marked as thread-unsafe as more of a lint. Doing anything useful with a raw pointer requires dereferencing it, which is already unsafe. In that sense, one could argue that it would be "fine" for them to be marked as thread safe."

Comment: That's exactly what I want is locking the value behind the pointer. Everytime I try to deref NonNull (which is inside an arc <mutex<>>) I get the same error as previously mentioned.

Comment: You should use both approaches: `MyNonNull` from @user4815162342 to get `Send` and `Arc<Mutex<_>>` to get locking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide an unsafe implementation of `Send` to inform the compiler that you've taken into account the thread-safety of the objects behind the pointer (which you did, since you want to use a mutex for synchronization). For example:

```
// Wrapper around `NonNull<RawType>` that just implements `Send`
struct WrappedPointer(NonNull<RawType>);
unsafe impl Send for WrappedPointer {}

// Safe wrapper around `WrappedPointer` that gives access to the pointer
// only with the mutex locked.
struct SafeType {
    inner: Mutex<WrappedPointer>,
}

impl SafeType {
    fn some_method(&self) {
        let locked = self.inner.lock();
        // use ptr in `locked` to implement functionality, but don't return it
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize the implementation of send is supposed to be blank (I do realize that the inner class/virtual function table that's pointed to still has to be safe to multithread as this assumes nothing needs to be done and bypasses the compiler essentially).